# Query a column and result with same value of another column in MS SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a question to run a query on MS SQL 2005 Management studio, I have a table as below structure,

|Receipt No.|    Item No.    |   Amount |

```
|   1     |    1    |  $10  |

|   1     |    X    |  $0   |

|   2     |    2    |  $10  |

|   2     |    X    |  $0   |
```

How can query with any Item No. X with associated any same Receipt No and a sum of Amount? Etc.

the result of 2 records of Receipt No. 2 and Item No. 2 and X with total amount $10 ($10+0), (actually both 4 records above should be resulted.)

Many Thank!

Patrick

Comment: please show your expected output

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      [Receipt No],
STUFF((    SELECT ',' + SUB.[Item No] 
            FROM table_name SUB
            WHERE
            SUB.[Receipt No] = MAIN.[Receipt No]
            FOR XML PATH('') 
            ), 1, 1, '' ) as [Item No]
            ,sum(Amount) as [Amount]

FROM  table_name MAIN
GROUP by  [Receipt No]
```

Comment: SELECT ReceiptNo, ItemNo, Amount

FROM MyTable

WHERE ReceiptNo IN

 (SELECT DISTINCT ReceiptNo FROM MyTable

 WHERE ItemNo = 'XXX')

Answer (score 0):

I got someone recommends this query...

SELECT ReceiptNo, ItemNo, Amount

FROM MyTable

WHERE ReceiptNo IN

(SELECT DISTINCT ReceiptNo FROM MyTable

WHERE ItemNo = 'XXX')